# Change height of rectangle with value in textbox

Tags: c#

I'm quite new to C# and I'm trying to change the height of a rectangle to the value of the number in my textbox when i press a button.

So when I hardcode it I get

```
private void btnGrafiek_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        rct2010.Height = 150;
    }
```

this is without the texbox and worked fine.
I thought I had to do this if I use a textbox:

```
private void btnGrafiek_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        rct2010.Height = txt2010.Text;
    }
```

But this doesn't work. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: **How** doesn't it work? What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: Height is an integer, but Text is a string.  This isn't safe, in case the string can't parse to an integer, but it will work for your simple example.

Comment: @BillGregg, No.  Height is a double.  Same difference to the context here, but worth pointing out since you were calling the OP out on it :)

Comment: @Garry.  True that.  Guess I should have left it generic and just said Height is numeric.  Thanks for keeping me honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Height is an integer, but Text is a string.  This isn't safe, in case the string can't parse to an integer, but it will work for your simple example.

```
private void btnGrafiek_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rct2010.Height = int.Parse(txt2010.Text);
}
```

To be really safe you would use TryParse.

```
private void btnGrafiek_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int height;
    if(int.TryParse(txt2010.Text,out height))
    {
       rct2010.Height = height;
    }
    else
    {
       rct2010.Height = 150;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Int.Parse works perfectly fine
I never expected such a fast response. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

convert it to an int

```
private void btnGrafiek_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        rct2010.Height = int.Parse(txt2010.Text);
    }
```

or you can go a step further

```
private void btnGrafiek_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    if(int.TryParse(txt2010.Text, out i)
        rct2010.Height = i;
    else
        MessageBox.Show("That's not a number");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the type of `Height` is `int`, and so assigning a value of type `string` won't work and you'll get a compile-time error stating as such (feel free to clarify); you'll need to convert the type, such as:

```
int height = 0;
if (int.Parse(txt2010.Text, out height)) {
  rct2010.Height = height;
}
```

The `TryParse` (as opposed to the otherwise suggested `Parse`) will ensure your application doesn't encounter an exception if the value cannot be parsed (i.e. it's bad, unexpected input). But then, on the other hand, this means your application apparently does nothing with the input (because it doesn't), so you may wish to use an `else` case to inform the user.